# Can't install PyArrow on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I have an EC2 Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS instance with python 3.6.9

I tried to install pyarrow with this command:

```
python3 -m pip install pyarrow
```

But I get an error:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;
__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3q5nmx81/pyarrow/setup.py';
f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-fgafmfzg-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" 
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3q5nmx81/pyarrow/
```

Reading the first messages after trying to install yarrow I see this:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyarrow ... error
```

Please, do you know how I can solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider filing a bugticket instead. Alternatively, extract a [mcve] and provide that here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are working in a virtual environment, it is likely that your pip version is the default one (`9.0.1`). Try to upgrade it with `pip install --upgrade pip` and run the command `python3 -m pip install pyarrow` again.

Tested under Ubuntu 18.04, with Python 3.6.9 and `pyarrow==4.0.0`

Comment: That's the answer I needed!, thank you @Gabriele Sarti